# recursively counting nodes in k-ary tree

Tags: recursion, tree

This isn't exactly homework but I need to understand it for a class.  Language doesn't really matter, psuedocode would be fine.

Write a recursive member function of the “static K-ary” tree class that counts the number of nodes in the tree.

I'm thinking the signature would look like this:

```
int countNodes(Node<AnyType> t, ctr, k){}
```

I don't know how to look through k children.  In a binary tree, I would check for left and right.  Could anyone give me an example of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of the recursive equation like:

The total number of nodes starting at a node is `1 + number of total children`. 
Then total number of nodes can be found as follows:

```
def count(node):
    numOfNodes = 1
    for child in node.children:
        numOfNodes += count(child)
    return numOfNodes
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to implement k-array tree whose output is in the form of adjacent matrix using Java. Input parameters are k=number of child for each node and d= depth of tree. given this parameter I am to generate adjacent matrix of the tree. I saw github and was not able to follow.can you please guide me to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudocode:

```
count(r)
    result = 1
    for each child node k
        result = result + count(k)
    return result
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to implement k-array tree whose output is in the form of adjacent matrix using Java. Input parameters are k=number of child for each node and d= depth of tree. given this parameter I am to generate adjacent matrix of the tree. I saw github and was not able to follow.can you please guide me to implement this?